# What does this sentence mean generally?

Tags: ambiguity

"I am off it"

What does this sentence mean generally? I am not well, interested etc?

Comment: It's certainly not a *well-established* idiomatic usage. Can you give any more context?

Comment: This sounds a perfectly normal expression to me. I would use it to mean 'not interested in X at the moment', especially with a sense of being displeased about the thing. eg "I'm a bit off football [since it became more about money and less about sport]" or "I'm a bit off John [since he behaved like such a jerk the other day]."

Comment: I would interpret it to mean "I'm a bit ill," or "I'm not thinking clearly," or some such, depending on the circumstances.  "I'm a bit off my game" is a better-known idiom meaning that you're not thinking clearly or perhaps not physically functioning well.

Comment: As recently edited, of course, the phrase could mean that the person is off drugs or off booze (or off Stack Exchange) -- kicked some sort of habit.  Or simply he has discontinued taking antibiotics or some such.  Or off a task force at work.  Loads of possible meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context it can mean *unwell*, *unfit*, or more likely from the sentence given, *stopped liking sth*.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=off) says

> ...
>
> adj.
>
> ...
>
> 4. No longer taking place; canceled: The wedding is off.
>
> ...
>
> 6.
>
> a. Not up to standard; below a normal or satisfactory level: Your pitching is off today.
>
> b. Not accurate; incorrect: Your statistical results are off.
>
> c. Somewhat crazy; eccentric: I think that person is a little off.

While not mentioned above, the example is in the vein of 6a and 6c.

It could also mean *nearby*, as in

> We live just off the main street.